# Make text appear in an input as I click on a button

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I am a novice when it comes to javascript and I need some help with a specific thing:

Make text appear in an input as I click on a button.

A bit of a situation: In a HTML form the user selects 2 tickets in a different input. Let's say each ticket is worth $5, I want the script to show the total price of the tickets in an input at the bottom.

[Here is how the script should behave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnurl.png)

Answer (score -1):

First make a variable for the total price. You will then need to write a formulae that multiplies the first input by the price (In this case $5) and saves this number to the variable created previously. Finally document.write this variable into the second input